# Flink Streaming - How to schedule DataStream to be reprocessed after X minutes?

Tags: flink-streaming

I have input data stream of events,

while processing them i would like to refer some of the events to be reprocessed again
after several minutes.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Here is a simplified example of what im trying to acheive:

```java
var delayedMessagesOutputTag = new OutputTag<Long>("delayedMessagesOutputTag") {};

var inputStream = env.fromElements(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L);
var resolvedElements = processEvents(delayedMessagesOutputTag, inputStream);

var delayedStream = resolvedElements
        .getSideOutput(delayedMessagesOutputTag);
        .process( /*** SOME MAGIC HERE TO CAUSE DELAY ***/);

var resolvedDelayedEvents = processEvents(delayedMessagesOutputTag, delayedStream);

resolvedElements
        .union(resolvedDelayedEvents)
        .addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());

env.execute();

....
private SingleOutputStreamOperator<Long> processEvents(OutputTag<Long> delayedMessagesOutputTag, DataStream<Long> inputStream) {
   // Returns resolved events, write desired delayed events to delayedMessagesOutputTag
}
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Flink Timers](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/#timers):

```java
...
final var delay = Duration.ofMinutes(1);
final var delayedStream = resolvedElements.getSideOutput(delayedMessagesOutputTag)
                .keyBy(new DelayedProcessFunction.KeySelectorImpl())
                .process(new DelayedProcessFunction(delay));
...
```

The `DelayedProcess` and `KeySelectorImpl` example realization:

```java
public class DelayedProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Long, Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Long delayMs;
    // we need to store delayed events
    private transient ValueState<Long> state;

    public DelayedProcessFunction(Duration delay) {
        delayMs = delay.toMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        // setup events state
        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("state", Long.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(Long value, KeyedProcessFunction<String, Long, Long>.Context ctx, Collector<Long> out) throws Exception {
        final var timerService = ctx.timerService();
        // for example we use registerProcessingTimeTimer() instead of registerEventTimeTimer()
        timerService.registerProcessingTimeTimer(timerService.currentProcessingTime() + delayMs);
        // store current value for onTimer() in the future
        state.update(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, KeyedProcessFunction<String, Long, Long>.OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Long> out) throws Exception {
        // pull out stored value for current random key (check getKey() realization below) and send to out dataStream
        out.collect(state.value());
        state.clear();
    }

    public static class KeySelectorImpl implements KeySelector<Long, String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public String getKey(Long value) {
            // random key for every event
            return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this code locally it works.

Comment: There's a a problem with this implementation. Flink expects that key selectors will be deterministic. By returning a random key, you've arranged for weird things to happen in some situations. In this specific case, e.g., you'll end up with duplicates after recovery from a checkpoint.